# Display Please wait while upgrading database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to upgrade my DB in next update, but I've faced with a problem. my upgrading is too heavy and spends 2-3 minute in device ( depends on hardware of device ) and it contains delete some table create table and move data from old table to new table, I don't want to user see white screen while upgrading, and as database upgrading is first command that runs I can't start any activity to see please waiting or any other data.

for solving this issue I've used `AsyncTask` class, in `onUpgrade` of database I execute an asyncTask class to do my upgrading, and I can start my splash screen to notify to user that application need some time. but with this solution I lost Transactional behaviour and if the device has been turned off, or application be killed my application faced with a bigger problem.

I know how to run my multiple codes in Transactional, but as I understand, database version has been increased and next time that I launch application database don't upgrade anymore and the application doesn't work anymore. ( because new table not exists).

I think on one solution to keep track my upgrade database and save into sharedPref and in the next launch check the value in sharedPreference and if upgrade has been complete let user to use application, else finish upgrade process.

I don't think that be the best way, so I want to ask you, is any other solution exists to upgrade the database in the background and if the problem happened database upgrade start over again?

Thanks in advance, and thanks for your time.

PS: I know if any error happened in onUpgrade, database upgrading start over but when I move upgrading from UI thread to back thread this not happened anymore, and I don't know why.

Comment: Can service be helpful?

Comment: no, service can't help me in this problem

Answer (score 1):

First I don't have enough reputation to comment that is why I am writing this answer.

Why don't you do that on server side? Use any server side scripting language and whenever you are upgrading database just put a lock on database and if user tries to access database display a message that "currently so and so is under Maintenance : come back after few minutes".

In this way you won't interfere in users work and user won't mine coming back in few minutes.

I think this is better than using sharedPreference in both speed and reliability.

Hope this helps. If you need any help in this do ask in comment.

Comment: this is not a good way, hole application work with database in each activity, and with your solution we force user to turn on internet, might be user don't want use internet.

Comment: Your database is at server. So even if you use any method ,user will have to connect to internet at least once to give command to upgrade database. Same is here. But only benefit here is user does not have to remain online everytime because code will run on server without user interference.

Comment: my database is not on sever, my data is saved on local database and server just sync data with local

Comment: Then best way is to add that upgradation part in an activity and make it run at background without user interaction. So for that use Services.

Comment: as i say user work with database from first activity, so if user launch application and don't see data it's very bad. thanks for your reply, I've use sharedPreference and i handle transactional upgrading